# Why ResultSet meteData getColumnName got all Upper case column name

Tags: java, sql, resultset

My query like below:

```
select a "Column A" from table
```

and I am using

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
metaData.getColumnName();
```

I got the column name as "COLUMN A" rather than "Column A".
I tried to use"

```
select a as ColumnA from table
```

Still got "COLUMN A"

Why ResultSet meteData getColumnName got all Upper case column name? How can I get the lowercase instead?

Comment: Are you using an Oracle database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And which JDBC driver (and version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getColumnName(i)` always returns the designated column's name, so, this problem is not related with the method but your database.
I think you've better check your database and see how the column names set.

**UPDATE:** I used this method with  MYSql and Sqlite and MS Acces, I didn't face any problem like that.

Comment: Thanks Azad. It is a db problem. Thank you so much!